# Bootstrap 3 multiple modal issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue regarding `Bootstrap 3 modals`. I have a button which opens a modal containing some content and an other button.

If this button is clicked, this modal gets closed and a new confirm modal is shown but I now have a scrollbar at the right side of my screen.

I see in the html code that the class `modal-open` is not added back again to the `body` tag.

I tried the following without success:

```
_btnConfirmResignation.click(function () {
    _modalResignation.modal('hide');

    _modalResignation.on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        //_modalConfirmResignation.modal('show');

        // EDIT: this works
        setTimeout(function () { _modalConfirmResignation.modal('show'); }, 0);
    });

    //_modalConfirmResignation.on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    //   $('body').addClass('modal-open');
    //});
});
```

Somebody that has a solution for this?

**EDIT**

My resignation modal:

```
    <!-- Modal Resignation -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalResignation" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalResignationLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalResignationLabel"><i class="icon-check"></i>Einde contract registreren</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="txtEmployeeDateResignation">Einddatum:</label>       
                            <div class="input-group date date-resignation">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmployeeDateResignation" CssClass="form-control" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="txtResignationRemark">Opmerking:</label>                              
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtResignationRemark" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="form-control" />    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i><span>Annuleren</span></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom" id="btnConfirmResignation"><i class="icon-ok"></i><span>Contract beëindigen</span></button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My confirmation modal:

```
<!-- Model confirm resignation -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalConfirmResignation" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalConfirmResignationLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalConfirmResignationLabel"><i class="icon-check"></i>Einde contract registreren</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <p>Bent u zeker dat u deze persoon zijn contract wil beëindigen? Indien u door gaat, wordt deze persoon volledig geblokkeerd.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i><span>Annuleren</span></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom" runat="server" id="btnSaveResignation" onserverclick="btnSaveResignation_click"><i class="icon-ok"></i><span>Bewaren en doorgaan</span></button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please also include the HTML for your modals. Further, are the items with underscores supposed to be variables that have been assigned to represent a specific control on the page, or is that how you're trying to access the page items?

Comment: I have added my html of my 2 modals. Yes they are variables that represent my controls.

Comment: I've done this but I used bootbox and on the close handler I launched the new modal - seemed to work well.

Comment: @ZachLeighton I will check into the `bootbox` to see if its working

Comment: I'm not seeing what the problem is. Made a fiddle, running it in Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/degoeym/uafc6ptd/ Can you confirm you're having your issue in more than one browser, and what browsers/versions of those browsers you're having the issue?

Comment: same issue in chrome. Your jsfiddle is indeed working here also...

Comment: if I do a setTimeout() then its working fine... Any ideas?

Comment: You need to setup the event handler (i.e. your `_modalResignation.on(` ) before you trigger the event (i.e. before your `_modalResignation.modal('hide')`), NOT afterwards like in your current code.

Comment: @cvrebert: still the same...